# Cancelling PayPal-Website Payments Standard's Payment Programmatically

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Is there any API available to Cancel or Modify a recurring payment created using PayPal - Website Payments Standard?
Or
Can I use Express Checkout APIs to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the subscription ID starts with I- you may be able to cancel them with `UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile`, but this is not guaranteed.
If they start with S-, you'll have to do it via the Recurring Payments Dashboard.